# puppeteer - Release control of chrome

Tags: puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

I want to semi-automate a business flow (invoice creation) by logging in to a specific website, creating a new invoice, pre-filling data, but after that point I wish to relinquish control to the user so that the data can be verified, and the invoice created by manually clicking the button.

So far I've got

```
(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false});
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.setViewport({width: 1600, height: 2400});

  console.log("SetViewPort");

  await page.goto('xxx/login');

  console.log("Logging in...");
  await page.screenshot({path: 'login.png'});

  await page.type('#loginform input[name=usrloginname]', 'xxx');
  await page.type('#loginform input[name=usrpassword]', 'xxx');
  await page.click('#loginform button');
  await page.waitForNavigation();


  console.log("Login submitted...");
  await page.screenshot({path: 'loggedin.png'});

  await page.goto('xxx/invoice/create');

  console.log("Get form for new invoice...");
  await page.screenshot({path: 'emptyinvoice.png'});


  await page.type('#form_newszla input[name=partnername]', name);
  await page.type('#form_newszla input[name=partnercity]', city);
....

   // ???! RELINQUISH CONTROL HERE

})();
```

Comment: Try reading this https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/372

Comment: I think you should create a chrome extension — it would fit your use case perfectly.

Comment: Are you wanting the user to be able to control Puppeteer (as in allow the user to write lines of code)? Or are you simply wanting to allow the user to make changes to the input in your form through the web page?

Comment: The latter. Just to type in their password, etc, or to verify the form before submitting it. Once that is done, I would like the code to "know" that it can continue with the automation. The use case is an integration to an invoicing app that does not have an actual API. The system would fill out the data, the user would check and push the submit button, and the system would continue with the rest of the automated steps.